# How to transform a network into another using Networkx

Tags: networking, graph, networkx

I have a graph like the movie database, i.e., actor acts in a movie. Then I need to transform this graph to another one which shows "actor A knows actor B". In Neo4j, you do the following as given at http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/11/using-apache-spark-and-neo4j-for-big.html:

MATCH (a1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors)
CREATE (a1)-[:KNOWS]->(coActors);

But as my graph is in Networkx, what would be the most efficient way of doing this without searching the whole graph for each node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the original graph is a bipartite graph. In networkx, we can use projected graph of a bipartite graph to generate new graphs. If two nodes has a common node in the bipartite graph, they will be linked in a projected graph.

```
X,Y=bipartite.sets(G)
G1 = bipartite.projected_graph(G, X, multigraph=False)
G2 = bipartite.projected_graph(G, Y, multigraph=False)
```